# How can detect an 'end-of-file' error, using code, when using readLAS?

Tags: r, lidr

While looping through my list of LAS files in a directory (I'm using readLAS to record warnings and errors for each file), at least one file gives an error message in the console window (i.e. ERROR: 'end-of-file' after 3355392 of 25918554 points). The error doesn't interrupt the loop but that file will be invalid. Is it possible to catch this in the code on the fly while reading the LAS file? Or does it have to be done after the loop finishes by reviewing message outputs in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is corrupted. The error is thrown from the LASlib library and is not strictly an error programmatically speaking. This is why no error or warning is thrown at the R level. It is printed in the standard R output so I guess the message can be captured with `capture.output()`. But anyway you should fix your file with e.g. `las2las` from LAStools.

Comment: thanks I'll go with the 'capture.output()'. Note, I tried the las2las tool from LAStools; but, while it allowed for further processing, it had truncated the data at the end-of-file part of the file. (this file I found out will be redelivered anyway).

Comment: If las2las truncates the file then `lidR` will likely truncate the file as well